# SQL join on string_split values

Tags: sql, t-sql

So, I have a column value something like this:

`1,15,32,64`

And another table (called infoTable) where the identifier and text is in seperate columns. What would be the best way to get the Data of the infoTable into an select from the mainTable ?

I've thought about string_split but cant find anything on how i should start with that.

Im currently using MS SQL Server Manager Studio.

Comment: sql server version plz?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583456) - 14.0.2037.2 (X64)   Nov  2 2020 19:19:59   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 18363: )

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `cross apply`:

```
select t.*, i.text
from maintable t cross apply
     string_split(t.ids, ',') s join
     infotable i 
     on i.id = s.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

below is the join

```
select i.* FROM infoTable i
INNER JOIN string_split('1,15,32,64',',') sp
on i.columname=sp.value
```

Comment: I dont quite get it.
Take a look at the code in the pastebin: https://pastebin.pl/view/8b9105ef
How should i implement it into that?

Comment: @MarcelH. create another question with your orginal problem